# No response from server LEMP (CentOS 5.5 final)

Tags: linux, nginx, centos5

I am having CentOS 5.5 (Final) 32 Bit and Nginx, MySql, php-fpm installed and running but when I try to open page from my configured domain nothing displays the browser keeps on loading. I tried with server IP also but still the same. Please help me out

Comment: even I am not able to connect with ftp ...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the firewall blocking it? By default I think it blocks pretty much everything but SSH. As root, try

```
/sbin/system-config-firewall-tui
```

to get the UI to configure this. (It might be `system-config-network` or `-security` - I can never remember.) You might also have to install some packages for this, i.e.

```
yum install /sbin/system-config-firewall-tui
```

but I find that easier that remembering my way around the separate config files.

(And if I've completely mis-remembered, try /usr/sbin in case the utilites are in there insetad.)

Comment: I checked the firewall with iptables and there is no blocking

Comment: OK, fair enough. Next I'd try looking in /var/log/httpd and the error logs in particular.

Comment: I have nginx so no httpd. I have checked /var/log/nginx/access.log and found the normal notice errors

Comment: Oops, sorry, missed that. I'd check the port binding using `netstat -anp` to make sure that nginx was really binding to 0.0.0.0:80 or port 80 on your external IP but if it is I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3074/nginx.conf
i got this responce from the command